# Jruby+Swt. How to implement continuously appending to the scrollable multiline text in the thread

Tags: swt, jruby

I need to implement gui  which include multiline textbox to display logs.

I use "file-tail" gem to read the stream from file. I added swt thread asyncExec for managing gui elements asynchronously. But when I execute the code the gui is freezes and nothing puts to the text area.

```rb
@display.asyncExec {
    File.open("path_to_the_file") do |log|
        log.extend(File::Tail)      
        log.backward(10)
        log.tail {|line|
            @text_area.append line
        }
    end
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping just the part that actually modifies the GUI into the asyncExec instead of the whole part that reads the file.

Comment: @Baz, many many thanks!!! You save my day and next days :) First I wrap with asyncExec only gui element - text_area. But the freeze is stay(). Then I wrap all this code with ruby Thread and voila, everything works perfectly!

Comment: Feel free to post it as an answer to your own question. I don't know JRuby and would probably just do something horrible if I try to fix your code myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked example to this thread (Thanks @Baz)

```rb
threads = Thread.new {
    File.open("path_to_the_file") do |log|
        log.extend(File::Tail)      
        log.backward(10)
        log.tail {|line|          
            @display.asyncExec {      
                @text_area.append line
            }
        }
    end   
}
```

Comment: it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" when I want to accept the answer

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Couldn't remember how long it takes before you can accept your own answer. Well then, just come back here in 2 days :)